# Escaped HTML in comment error popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design, error-message

I tried to use goo.gl to shorten a long link, and was blocked by the system.  The popup error contained some non-rendered HTML. It looks like this should have been rendered as a new line and bold, but instead was escaped.

[image: popup with escaped html]

> <br> <b>Editors:</b> please replace the short URL noted above with the URL it redirects to!<br>

Comment: Regardless of the comment the question still stands. This does look like a bug.

Comment: Workaround: Don't post shortened links.

Comment: This post isn't about why the error was returned, it's about the content in the error message.

Comment: Nobody seems to have pointed out here that not only is the message rendered wrongly, its content is nonsensical. Non-mods can't edit other users' comments, so showing a message addressed to *editors* on *comment submission* makes no sense.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and assume that is the same error message as when trying to use a short link in a post.

Comment: @TinyGiant: It's the same error message, but unless this issue was fixed in the last few hours, it is correctly interpreted as HTML on questions: http://i.imgur.com/6yxEqA3.png

Comment: I'm thinking those are probably two different error pop-up functions. I seem to recall there only being one (of that style), but there could be two. @Cᴏʀʏ

Comment: @davidism: *whoosh*

Comment: It's still non-sensical even then. Editors cannot replace text that is blocked from being posted in the first place. Somebody has turned on this particular message without bothering to actually read it and/or engage some brainpower to decide whether it works in that location.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Someone has an old post, and they are editing it.  WHILE EDITING IT they are not permitted to commit their changes until all shortened URLs are cleaned up, as the system won't let you submit an edit with shortened URLs.  The fact that this shows up in contexts where you are not editing an ancient post with an embedded shortened URL that was there before you started is a minor UX issue, but I could see it taking effort to make it only show up when it makes contextual sense.

Comment: @Yakk: Hmm, I see, so by "Editors:" it really means "If this message popped up when you were editing an existing post:". Not very clear really.

Comment: The escaped HTML characters are a bug. As @Cᴏʀʏ pointed out, it works correctly for questions. Will fix tomorrow.

Comment: @MichaelStum [tag:status-planned], then?

Comment: @MDXF More like "status in-progress". I'm doing a transatlantic flight tomorrow and don't want to check in stuff until I'm actually back home, but it's pretty much good to do.